# Send mail only once in while result php

Tags: php, email, while-loop

I have this code

```
while($row = $rs->fetch_object()){
    echo $curl->get($row->site_url, 'sitekontrol', $row->id ).""; 
    if($row->site_url == "changed") {
        sendmail($mailadress);
    }
}
```

this sent to many times. i want to send just once on complate result.

This is sitecontrol system 
[image]

This is while 
[image]

Comment: You have to first explain the overall picture so we can understand the problem.

Comment: Then move `sendmail()` outside of the loop?  The whole point of a loop is to perform an action multiple times.

Comment: If you are ok with sending an email as soon as the `if` condition is true, just `break;` after it.

Comment: how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: added photo. can you check it again please.!!

Comment: Please dont post pictures of code

Comment: Your question is poorly asked and very unclear. As such you are getting people **guessing** i.e. @Brian answer. If you are more specific about what you are trying to do someone will almost definitely give you some useful assistance, but as it stands all we can do is guess what you want to do

Comment: Sorry for my english. i cant write totally.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send the results once 10 sites change, you will have to keep track of this variable.

You may want to do something like this:

```
$changes = 0;

while($row = $rs->fetch_object() && $changes < 10){
    echo $curl->get($row->site_url, 'sitekontrol', $row->id ).""; 
    if($row->site_url == "changed") {
        $changes++;
    }
}

if($changes >= 10) {
    sendmail($mailadress);
}
```

EDIT: Changed to Federico klez Culloca's solution.

Comment: why not just calling `sendmail` and than break, without the need for the boolean?

Comment: sorry, that's a far better solution

Comment: i edit my question. can you check it again please. (mailgonder) function sending mail!

Comment: When you are sending the mail, do you want to include all the rows that were changed?

Comment: Yes. i want to send one mail if changed 10 sites @Brain